# How can I create context-sensitive reference names for an environment which defines label prefixes on-the-fly?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem, cleveref, capitalization, small-caps

*Background: I asked a rather muddled but [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302716/creating-new-counter-formats-on-the-fly-with-enumitems-addenumeratecounter) earlier. I received an [excellent answer from Manuel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302720/) to that question but my confusion about the problem means that I unfortunately asked the wrong question. So this is a different question, despite the similar content, which I hope may be* a *right question, even if not* the *right question to ask.*

---

I am trying to create a new environment to typeset an enumerated list. The environment is designed to take one mandatory argument, typically a single letter. This is used as a prefix for items in the list. So if the letter is `a`, the items will be labelled `a1`, `a2` and so on. The labels are typeset so that the letter is in small-caps. References to items should also use small-caps except that sometimes I want the letter set in upper-case e.g. at the beginning of a sentence.

I have been trying to combine `cleveref` and `enumitem` to achieve this result. The labels within the list are unproblematic since `label=\textsc{<letter>}\arabic*` does the job nicely.

In order to facilitate different formats at the beginning of sentences, however, I've used `enumitem`'s `ref` option alongside `label`. I then would like to have `\Cref` and `\cref` format the label appropriately. However, I cannot figure out how to do this.

If I include the letter in the item's reference e.g. `ref=<letter>\arabic*`, then I can use `\creflabelformat{<type>}{<format>}` to typeset the label in, say, small-caps. But this isn't sensitive to context. `\Cref` and `\cref` assume that any difference in capitalisation will affect the *name* associated with the reference type and not the content of the specific item reference itself.

For this reason, I'm using `ref=\arabic*` and attempting to set the letter prefix using `\crefname` and `\Crefname`. However, this means that I need to create custom formats using `\crefname` and `\Crefname` inside my custom environment. The problem is that these definitions are not global so they are not defined when I use `\cref` or `\Cref` elsewhere in the document.

How can I achieve the desired result without predefining `\crefname` and `\Crefname` for the letters I need in advance?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem,cleveref,ebgaramond}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{lettered}{ O {} m }{%
  \let\labelorig\label
  \def\label##1{\labelorig[lettered#2]{##1}}%
  \crefname{lettered#2}{\textsc{#2}}{\textsc{#2}}%
  \Crefname{lettered#2}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textsc{#2}\arabic*., ref=\arabic*, #1]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\begin{document}
Some examples:
\begin{lettered}{t}
  \item\label{t:thing} A thing.
  \item\label{t:another} Another thing.
\end{lettered}
\begin{lettered}{c}
  \item\label{c:claim} A claim.
  \item\label{c:different} A different claim.
\end{lettered}
The actual output is the next sentence.
\Cref{t:thing} and \cref{t:another} are the subject of claims \cref{c:claim} and \cref{c:different}.
The desired output is the next sentence.
T1 and \textsc{t}2 are the subject of claims \textsc{c}1 and \textsc{c}2.
\end{document}
```

[image: prefixed referencing]

Answer (score 3):

OK. I'm an idiot. I can stare at something all afternoon but only find the answer 30 seconds *after* I post a question.

It turns out that `cleveref`'s documentation just has a weird idea of what constitutes a 'single' reference. I naïvely assumed that `Single Cross-References` meant cross-reference *tokens* and that

> Cross-reference formats for *single* cross-references are defined or
>   redefined using the `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat` commands ...

introduced a discussion about typesetting cross-reference *tokens*.

But it turns out that the documentation is referring to single *types* of cross-references rather than single *tokens* of cross-references, as I'd assumed. And that means that I can simply use `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat` with a single *type* of cross-reference for all labels created within my custom environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem,cleveref,ebgaramond}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{lettered}{ O {} m }{%
  \let\labelorig\label
  \def\label##1{\labelorig[lettered]{##1}}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textsc{#2}\arabic*., ref=#2\arabic*, #1]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\crefformat{lettered}{#2\textsc{#1}#3}
\Crefformat{lettered}{#2\MakeUppercase{#1}#3}
\begin{document}
Some examples:
\begin{lettered}{t}
  \item\label{t:thing} A thing.
  \item\label{t:another} Another thing.
\end{lettered}
\begin{lettered}{c}
  \item\label{c:claim} A claim.
  \item\label{c:different} A different claim.
\end{lettered}
The actual output is the next sentence.
\Cref{t:thing} and \cref{t:another} are the subject of claims \cref{c:claim} and \cref{c:different}.
The desired output is the next sentence.
T1 and \textsc{t}2 are the subject of claims \textsc{c}1 and \textsc{c}2.
\end{document}
```

And here is the result of typesetting a single cross-reference *type* involving four cross-reference *tokens*:

[image: a single cross-reference]